# Javascript optimization: What tool can condense sequential string concatenations?

Tags: javascript, optimization, string-concatenation

This is a simplified example, but I am working on a code translator that outputs javascript.  Due to the way the parsing is done, I have to output the translation in pieces.  I.e. I end up with a javascript file that looks similar to the following but much much longer:

```
function coolfunc() {
    var result = "";
    greet = function(user,town) {
        var output = '';
        output += 'Welcome ' + user + '!';
        output += 'How is the weather in ' + town + '?';
        return output;
    }
    goobye = function(user,town) {
        var output = '';
        output += 'Farewell ' + user + '!';
        output += 'Enjoy the weather in ' + town + '!';
        return output;
    }
    result += "Some output 1";
    result += "Some output 2";
    result += greet("Larry","Cool town");
    result += goobye("Larry","Cool town");
    return result;
}
```

Is there any post-processor I could use to condense the above into something like the following:

```
function coolfunc() {
    greet = function(user,town) {
        var output = 'Welcome ' + user + '!'+'How is the weather in ' + town + '?';
        return output;
    }
    goobye = function(user,town) {
        var output = 'Farewell ' + user + '!'+'Enjoy the weather in ' + town + '!';
        return output;
    }
    var result = "Some output 1"+"Some output 2"+greet("Larry","Cool town")+goobye("Larry","Cool town");
    return result;
}
```

If it could combine adjacent static string concatenations that would be gravy.

I figured that yuicompressor or closure compiler would do so, but as far as I can tell they don't.

---

Edit:

Comments so far seem to be telling me to do this in the translator.  I do not think this is the best option because it would make reading the translation very difficult...  similar to why people write verbose code and then minify it for production.

Comment: Are you worried about performance or bandwidth? Because this really isn't a big deal performance-wise…

Comment: Try a templating engine; it should better separate code and markup/messages and will probably be slightly more performant.

Comment: @Matchu: bandwidth.  It isn't a big deal but it just seems silly to keep all of the unnecessary variable names.

Comment: @davin: that doesn't really help me but thanks for reading my question.

Comment: This sure seems like it would be easier to fix in the translator rather than reparse javascript from scratch to try to fix it.

Comment: @jfriend00: why?  It would only run the the post-processor once.  Do you not run your javascript through yuicompressor or closure compiler?  Isn't that the same principle?

Comment: I agree with jfriend00 - do it in the translator. Also, if you're really keen to condense the code and remove "unnecessary variable names" you can remove the `output` and `result` variables altogether and just directly return the result of the string concatenation.

Comment: I say do it in the translator because you already have the code in parsed form and you just need to generate more efficient code.  If you could just run it through closure and have it magically fixed, that would be fine but apparently closure doesn't have that feature so now you're comparing building your own post processor vs. fix the translator.  I know which one I'd pick.

Comment: @jfriend00 Okay... from that perspective, I agree that the best option is to do it in the translator.  However, I asked if anyone knew of an existing minimizer that could do this.  I did not say I wanted to write a post processor.

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes, returning the concatenation would be one step better.  Good point.

Comment: I was just assuming that you hadn't found a post processor that would do what you want and weren't likely to.  I jumped to that conclusion - a little ahead of where you are I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone comes across this, it looks like closure compiler can handle this as of revision 1576 (http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/detail?r=1576)